# How do you find out about the quality of a Skin?

Tags: league-of-legends

How can you find out if a skin is legendary, epic or something else? Can I distinguish between the qualities by solely looking at the price or are there any other factors that I should note?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [wiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_skin) has a good article about skins

As a summary:

There are 7 Prices For Skins (390, 520, 750, 975, 1350, 1820, 3250 RP) and only the 2 most expensive ones have official names: Legendary (1820) and Ultimate (3250).

The community often also uses Semi-Legendary, Ex-Legendary or Epic to describe the 1350 skins since these often were old legendary skins (At the start of league there were only 3 categories: 520, 975 and 1820).

The 975/750 RP skins are often simply called "normal" skins while the 520 or below are often referred to as "minor" skins.

The following is a rule that can be followed **but it does not apply for every single skin. Just for most**:

**Ultimate Skin**:

- Summoners Icon (Always)
- Summoners Banner (Always)
- New Voiceover (Always)
- Extreme Character modification (Always)
- Special Effects on spells (Always)
- Special Sounds on spells (Always)
- Special Quotes/Animations reacting to the Map/Situation (Always)

**Legendary Skin**:

- New Voiceover (Almost Always)
- Special Effects on spells (Almost Always)
- Heavy Character modification (Always)
- Special Sounds on spells (Often)
- Special Quotes (Often)

**Epic Skins**:

- Heavy Character modification (Often)
- Special Effects on spells (Sometimes)
- Special Sounds on spells (Rarely)
- New Quotes (Very Rare)

**Normal-Skins**:

- Normal Character modification (Always)
- Special Effects on spells (Sometimes)
- New Quotes (Very Rare)

**Minor Skins**:

- Light character Modification (Always)

A thing to note: Event skins often cost 750 RP. While these are still in the price category "normal", they often do have more special effects than normal or even epic skins.

Then there are also Legacy Skins which used to be normal buyable skins, but now they return once or twice a year.

### The rarest "Forever Unavailable" skins

**Event-Skins** like the Pax or Riot skins (Pax Twisted Fate can cost up to 1000$ nowadays!!)

**Reward skins** like Black Alistar/Human Ryze (Pre-Order the game in 2009), Triumphant Ryze (Win an official tournament), King Rammus (Play the beta), Victorious Skins (Gold or above in Ranked), Judgement Kayle (Win 10 games in Season 1) and UFO Corki (got automatically rewarded to players in 2009). There Is no way to obtain these skins right now except for human ryze which may be bought on Ebay or similar sites (But expect to pay 300$+)

**The "Lost" Skins** are often considered the rarest skins. There are only 2: Rusty Blitzcrank who was "Too Ugly" ([No joke!](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Blitzcrank/SkinsTrivia)) and Urf the Manatee Warwick which was basically an Easter Egg.

Comment: so skins like the udyr spirit guard and ezreal pulsefire are the only ult skins right now?

Comment: @ken yes indeed. Dunkmaster Darius is announced but not final.

Comment: @Jutschge do you even have a job or go to school XD ?

Comment: @IbrahimApachi working with computers ;). I never answer questions when I'm at home.

Comment: use the model viewer if you are unsure ! http://www.lolking.net/models

Comment: don't forget about the championship skins (riven and thresh for now)

Comment: Also lolking model viewer doesn't show you all about the skin, you should also watch the skin spotlight videos from youtube to see if there are also additional or different visual/sound effects and voice quotes the same skin have.

Comment: What do you mean by saying that for example Pax Twisted Fate costs up to 1000$. Is there any way to sell skins? Or are you talking about selling the whole account? I'M just curious!

Comment: @Toby Pax skins were only available through skin cards (you enter a code in the client, then you recieve the skin) and one of these codes can cost between 300-1000$ on ebay depending on how many offers there are currently. Remember that there are only about 1000-2000 total Pax TF skins total. I've played about 6000 games and I've only seen one!